# How do you customize shared access signature for logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an azure logic app with an HTTP trigger.  The http trigger has an auto generated shared access signature.  Is it possible to programatically generate this URL?  If so, any example out there?   Is it possible to include arbitrary data in the shared access signature to give the client / server more context for the HTTP call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to programatically generate this URL?

Yes, you could generate SAS token with program. Here are two service generating SAS token sample code.One is [Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token), one is [Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2#part-1-create-a-console-application-to-generate-shared-access-signatures).

> Is it possible to include arbitrary data in the shared access
>   signature to give the client / server more context for the HTTP call?

Generate SAS token has its principles. You could only pass parameters allowed by REST API and needed by token.Like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#generate-a-shared-access-signature-token) lists mostly parameters needed.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: @user2368632 if my answer could help you, could you accept my answer?Thanks!